# How can I remove a line from a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to be able to delete specific lines from a csv file using the pandas. This is what I have so far:

```
def delete_from_file():
    student_name = input("What is the name of the student? ")
    df = pd.read_csv('students.csv', names = ['name', 'phone number', 'class time', 'duration'], index_col=0)
    df.drop(student_name)
    print(df)
```

and this is what a sample line from the csv file looks like:

"Carl Henderson,900-122-818,12:15pm,30 mins"

I want to be able to write "Carl Henderson" for the student_name and basically have the whole row removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to

```
def delete_from_file(student_name):
    df = pd.read_csv('students.csv', names = ['name', 'phone number', 'class time', 'duration']).set_index('name')
    df=df.drop(student_name)
    return df
```

Comment: I still get the same error, which is "['student_name'] not found in axis". Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: @rod.hoda not "student_name" should be student_name